# What is the best way to update a textbox forecolour when the value within the textbox has been changed?

Tags: angular, typescript

*I'm relatively new to Angular so apologies if this is a simple problem, however I couldn't find any solution to this specific issue from research I have performed.*

I have multiple textboxes that are generated dynamically. I want to ensure that any textbox which has its value changed will have its text turn red.

I have a css class to handle this, and I have attempted using [ngClass] with a function behind to do a comparison with the old and new value, but I can't find a way in Angular to grab the original value in the textbox before it has been edited. I've also tried using *dirty* and *pristine* but no such luck.

For example

```
<input class="input" matInput placeholder="Quantity [(ngModel)]="row.valueOneA" name="valueOneA" [ngClass]="{'redForeColour': row.valueOneA.dirty}">
```

I also attempted to store a variable in the ts code, which is then used for comparison purposes, but unfortunately this will change **all** of the textboxes to red, and I only want the one that has its value updated to change.

This is not to signify an input is invalid / incorrect, so using a form validator would not be suitable for this. It is solely to indicate to a user that the value of the input has been changed so that they are aware of this before saving those changes.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this, or is there a way in Angular we can grab the initial value in the textbox for comparison purposes?

Comment: Can you show the sample Demo in the stackblitz? or overall code that is relevant to this question

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I can quickly whip something up to show what I've attempted. As I said though, I've tried quite a lot of different methods, none of which worked, so I don't want to bloat the question. Is there a particular attempt method you would like to see that I can provide?

Comment: You can user ```Directive``` For change color while changing textbox value. directive will be applied into each TextBox where you want to change color.

Comment: @Sameer the issue I had with that is that it will change every textbox to red when only one is changed ; I would like it so that the textbox that is changed is the only one that goes red. If this is possible, I'd really appreciate if you could show me to how to achieve this please!

Comment: interested in the how you are gererating textboxes and what you tried!

Comment: Do you want to turn the color red to indicate that the field is invalid? If so I'd suggest reading up on custom validators (https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators), and using the invalid form styles to make the text red

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I've tried a lot of different ways and I don't have the time to set up a demo for each different attempt, haha. The short version is that the textboxes are generated using an ngModel which is populated from a mat-Table datasource. Each input is then populated with the value brought over from that datasource ; so for example, if there are 3 rows, there are 3 textboxes - 4 rows, 4 textboxes, etc. That's all I can really provide before I end up bloating the question with crazy amounts of code for different attempts.

Comment: @tim545 No, it's only to signify to the user that the input value has changed, so that they are aware of any changes they have made before saving those changes. I will update the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Can you use a custom directive to achieve this?

Comment: @NicholasK Possibly, but I'm not very experienced with Angular so I'd have no idea where to even begin with something like that - if you have any advice, I'd be very grateful to hear it!

Comment: I've created a sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8svs7f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) (this doesn't use any directive to make things simpler). Let me know if this approach would be helpful for you.

Comment: @NicholasK this is exactly what I'm after! Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it please. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template you can make use of the `ngStyle` directive and the `(change)` event of the input tag.

.html

```
<input (change)="flag1=true" [ngStyle]="{
  'color': flag1 ? 'red' : 'black'
}">
```

Note:

Since you have mentioned that these text boxes are dynamic you can always create a *variable* for each input box. Here's the corresponding [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8svs7f) for the same.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was after. I had a bit of an issue with multiple textboxes changing (the way it was initially written meant that the textboxes for each row from the datasource were called the same thing, so they would all change, but have tweaked this now). Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help..!

Answer (score 0):

you need a reference to the ngModel, use templateRef or formControl,

`<input class="input" matInput #input="ngModel" placeholder="Quantity [(ngModel)]="row.valueOneA" name="valueOneA" [ngClass]="{redForeColour: input.dirty}">`

or

`<input class="input" matInput placeholder="Quantity formControlName="valueOneAControl" [ngClass]="{redForeColour: valueOneAControl.dirty}">`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what I can do with these changes that will allow me to implement what I'm after please? I've tried #input but it doesn't have any value that I can then use for comparison.